# Why does "delete branch after merge" delete only the remote GIT branch and not the local?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-merge, git-branch

Just as the title suggests, when I approve a merge request from the repository webpage and check the "delete branch after merge", only the remote branch is removed. I don't understand why the the local branch is kept on my computer. What happens if I proceed modifying that local branch, can I still push it and merge it?

Answer (score 4):

Git is a decentralised version control system.
You need to synchronise your local with origin if you want to apply origin changes in your local.

To synchronise branches you can use `git fetch -p`.

If you dont want to delete local branch you can keep using it and it will appear on origin once you push it again.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the remote version of the branch is done automatically, because the entity asking if you want to do this is probably the remote repository.  Leaving tons of already merged branches on the remote can end up taking a lot of space, and eventually can hinder performance.  As to whether or not you also want to delete your local branch, it is a decision left up to you.

Yes, you may keep using that local branch and push again.  It will appear once again on the remote, and you could, in theory, even raise a new pull request from this once deleted branch to some target branch.  However, most Git users would opine that once a feature branch has been merged, its lifecycle is complete, and the branch should for the most part become retired and not used after the merge.

Answer (score 1):

The local repository and remote repository do not stay in constant contact, rather they are only updated with each others' state when git commands are run which interact with a remote repository. (Generally all the commands which include `origin`.)

My favorite way to cleanup merged local branches is as follows:

> `git branch -d merged-branch`

This will only delete `merged-branch` if it's contents are in another local branch, so it prevents deleting any unsaved local work.

> `git remote prune origin`

This checks which branches no longer exist on the origin and deletes those remote pointers. (It can also be run with `--dry-run` at the end to show what would be deleted without actually doing it.) This is the same as the command Kevin listed, except it does not fetch new references.